# How do I display errors in an component view with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

In my recent Angular 2 project, I try to add a component which displays all sorts of errors. I can manipulate and display the errors in the Chrome developer console, but I fail when it comes to actually generate output from them.

To achieve this, I added a service-class which extends the `ErrorHandler` of the Angular Core. It contains a Subject which you can subscribe to, to get new messages.

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export interface IMiaErrorMessage {
    exception: string,
    stackTrace?: any,
    reason?: string
}


@Injectable()
export class MiaErrorHandlingService extends ErrorHandler {

    public errors: Subject<IMiaErrorMessage> = new Subject<IMiaErrorMessage>();

    handleError(exception: any): void {
        console.groupCollapsed('Fehler');
        console.error(exception);
        console.groupEnd();
        let error: IMiaErrorMessage = {
            "exception": ""+exception
        }
        console.log('error', error);
        this.errors.next(error);

    }
}
```

Afterwards I added a component which should actually display the error messages. There is a `subscribe`-call which adds new error-messages the `errors`-Array. The two functions `throwError` and `addError` are for testing. When I simply add the exception text using the `addError` function everything works just fine, but not when i actually throw an error using `throwError`. The console output for both is the same.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MiaErrorHandlingService, IMiaErrorMessage } from './../services/mia-error-handling.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'mia-errors',
    templateUrl: 'errors.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['errors.component.scss'],
    providers: [MiaErrorHandlingService]

})
export class ErrorsComponent {
    title = 'Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten';

    private errors: Array<IMiaErrorMessage> = [];

    constructor(private miaErrorHandlingService: MiaErrorHandlingService) {

        // Observer of the connection status
        this.miaErrorHandlingService.errors.subscribe(
            value => this.errors.push(value),
            error => console.info('ERROR', error),
            () => console.info('COMPLETE')
        );

    }

    private throwError() {
        console.log('throwError');
        throw Error('Hello again');
    }

    private addError() {
        console.log('addError');
        this.miaErrorHandlingService.handleError('Foo');
    }

}
```

The console output is

```
errors.component.ts:35 addError
mia-error-handling.service.ts:18 Fehler
mia-error-handling.service.ts:19 FooMiaErrorHandlingService.handleError @ mia-error-handling.service.ts:19 ErrorsComponent.addError @ errors.component.ts:36_View_ErrorsComponent0._handle_click_13_0 @ ErrorsComponent.ngfactory.js:164(anonymous function) @ view.js:404(anonymous function) @ dom_renderer.js:249(anonymous function) @ dom_events.js:26ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:43ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:202Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:110NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:72NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:236outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:26ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:304
mia-error-handling.service.ts:24 error Objectexception: "Foo"__proto__: Object
errors.component.ts:30 throwError
mia-error-handling.service.ts:18 Fehler
mia-error-handling.service.ts:19 ViewWrappedError {_nativeError: Error: Error in ./ErrorsComponent class ErrorsComponent - inline template:10:8 caused by: Hello agai…, originalError: Error: Hello again
    at ErrorsComponent.throwError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:67888:15)…, context: DebugContext}MiaErrorHandlingService.handleError @ mia-error-handling.service.ts:19next @ application_ref.js:273schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:64ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ ng_zone_impl.js:72NgZone.runGuarded @ ng_zone.js:236outsideHandler @ dom_events.js:26ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:304
mia-error-handling.service.ts:24 error Objectexception: "Error: Error in ./ErrorsComponent class ErrorsComponent - inline template:10:8 caused by: Hello again"__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: __proto__()set __proto__: __proto__()
```

For the sake of completeness here is my view

```
    <dl *ngFor="let error of errors">
        <dt>
            <app-icon>warning</app-icon>
        </dt>
        <dd>{{error.exception}}</dd>
    </dl>
<button (click)="throwError()">Do something wrong!</button>
<button (click)="addError()">addError</button>
```

I'm thankful for every input I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cory Rylan has a great implementation of this in his blog post:
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management

I am using his method in my app:

Here is the error component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from '../services/validation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'kg-errorMessages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ErrorMessagesComponent {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() { }

  get errorMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the validation service:

```
//Original version created by Cory Rylan: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management
import { IsValidDate } from '../helpers/date.helper'


export class ValidationService {
    static getValidatorErrorMessage(validatorName: string, validatorValue?: any) {
        let config = {
            'required': 'Required',
            'invalidNumberField': 'Only numbers allowed',
            'invalidDateField': 'Not a valid date',
            'invalidCreditCard': 'Is invalid credit card number',
            'invalidEmailAddress': 'Invalid email address',
            'invalidPassword': 'Invalid password. Password must be at least 6 characters long, and contain a number.',
            'invalidPasswords': 'Invalid passwords. Passwords must match.',
            'minlength': `Minimum length ${validatorValue.requiredLength}`
        };

        // console.log(" config = " + JSON.stringify(config));
        // console.log(" validator name: " + validatorName);
        // console.log(" config = req " + JSON.stringify(config["required"]));
        // console.log(" config = nan " + JSON.stringify(config["invalidNumberField"]));
        return config[validatorName];
    }

    static numberFieldValidator(control) {
        // if (control.value.match(/^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$/)) {
        //     return null;
        // } else {
        //     return { 'invalidNumberField': true };
        // }

        return null;
    }

    static dateFieldValidator(control) {
        var e: boolean;

        if (IsValidDate(control.value)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidDateField': true };
        }
    }

    static creditCardValidator(control) {
        // Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Diners Club, Discover, JCB
        if (control.value.match(/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidCreditCard': true };
        }
    }

    static emailValidator(control) {
        // RFC 2822 compliant regex
        if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
        }
    }

    static passwordValidator(control) {
        // {6,100}           - Assert password is between 6 and 100 characters
        // (?=.*[0-9])       - Assert a string has at least one number
        if (control.value.match(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,100}$/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidPassword': true };
        }
    }

    static passwordCompareValidator(fg) {
        if (fg.value.password === fg.value.confirmPassword) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidPasswords': true };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11722) may also be of interest.